# Do power logs in the iOS file system only store for ~5 days?

Tags: ios, filesystem

Ive been browsing through the iOS file system with Filza File Manager on my iPad iOS 9.3.6 that is jailbroken. Ive found where power logs are logged as well as the power logs for the past few days within the 'Archive' folder. However, from what I've found, it only stores power logs for ~5 days. I need to find older logs though, like dating back a 1-2 months. Is there a way to find these or no? Thanks